# Insert gif in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, gif

It is possible to insert a img  gif and make it move inside a word document ?

Inserting a gif is possible but, it just shows the first img. I can't find the answer on google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word is for creating printed text documents. You might be better off using powerpoint, or creating a html page.

It's possible to extract all the layers out of a .gif file with a graphics editor such as photoshop, gimp or similar.

You could then save all your layers and paste them into your document and/or write some kind of macro that will display the images one after the other.
But I wouldn't recommend it, as anyone looking at your document would have to enable your macro.

Comment: P.S. You can add a .gif file to Word and save it as a web page to get the animation.

Answer (score 2):

GIF is not supported in Word from 2007 version onwards.

[Source](http://help.lockergnome.com/office/miss-gif-support-Microsoft-Office-2007-Outlook-plz-comm--ftopict906654.html) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20150930082425/http://help.lockergnome.com/office/miss-gif-support-Microsoft-Office-2007-Outlook-plz-comm--ftopict906654.html))

Answer (score 2):

1. Keep the Gif into a power point slide.
2. Save the slide
3. And insert the slide into word document and save the document.

The Gif shall not animate within the document. When the image is clicked (in fact a PPT slide) it will animate outside the document.

This is the only work around for inserting Gif into word document which shall animate, of course as an independent object outside the doc file.

Comment: Nice, this actually works well presuming the person you are sending the document to also has Powerpoint

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer; no, because Word is a word processor. You would have to save the document as an HTML file and view it in a browser for the animation to work.